# Relational query on PFObject

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a `PFObject`, `Account` that contains an array of `User`s which are subclasses of `PFUsers`s. The `User` then has a `NSDictonary` property, `allowableApps`, that's a `NSDictionary` of arrays, where they arrays contain `PFObject`s.

So as a structure:

**Account**

```
var users:   [User]
```

which points to....

**User**

```
// Each key is an array of AllowApp
var allowableApps: NSMutableDictionary
```

which points to...

**AllowableApp**

```
var appName: String
var appURL:  String
var isAllowed: Bool
```

I'm trying to fetch all of these relations down to `AllowableApp` in a single query. I've tried using the `.includeKey` like this:

```
accountQuery?.includeKey("users")
accountQuery?.includeKey("allowableApps")
```

which didn't work. I've also tried:

```
accountQuery?.includeKey("users.allowableApps.appName")
accountQuery?.includeKey("users.allowableApps.appURL")
accountQuery?.includeKey("users.allowableApps.isAllowed")
```

---

I try to populate a `UITableView` with all the `AllowableApp` objects but I get this error:

```
Key "appName" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.
```

Which I understand, I need to fetch all of them before trying to access the `appName` property. (which I'm trying to set `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

---

Here is my full query:

```
let currentUser = User.currentUser()
        let accountQuery = Account.query()

        accountQuery?.whereKey("primaryUser", equalTo: currentUser!)
        accountQuery?.includeKey("users.allowableApps")

        accountQuery?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (account, error) in

            if (error != nil) {
                completion(users: nil, error: error)
            }
            else {
                let users = (account as? Account)!.users
                completion(users: users, error: nil)
            }
        })
```

---

My thought right now is to just loop through all of the `AllowableApp` objects in `viewDidAppear` calling `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock`. Then once they are all loaded I reload the table data.

This seems realllly messy and a common problem. Is there a more elegant solution that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you have the following structure:

- Account

  - Users (Array of User)

    - AllowsableApps (Array of AllowApps)

First of all change the **NSMutableDictionary** to **Array**. NSMutableDictionary is a key-value pairs and in parse you should create one field. So you can use Array of AllowApps and it will do the same effect.

In order to fetch all accounts and users in each of the account and allowable apps per user you need to build the following query:

```
    // You can do it with sub classing if you want
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Account")
    query.includeKey("users.allowableApps")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    }
```

Now for your users array. If your users array is users that needs to login the app it's better to inherit from **PFUser** and not from **PFObject** because **PFUser** contains all the logic for handling users in your app.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! My structure is more `Account` -> `Users` -> `AllowableApps` if that makes sense. Also, I'm using a `NSMutableDictionary` because they keys are section header views in my table. I guess I could in theory have a `AppCategory` that's a `PFObject` that has an array of `AllowableApps` but it seemed robust just hold a category name.

Comment: Hi , yes the allowable apps should be under the users from i guess my indentation now worked well :) (i will update my answer). Anyway please try to change your code according to the answer because i refer to the same structure as you are..

Comment: I've updated my question to have the full query I'm running. When I try your suggested code I get an error of `can only include pointer fields`??

Comment: That is very strange... did you created some ACL's on your objects ?